# Add field to an user during creation django

Tags: python, django, forms, user-registration

I want to add a field "full_access" to an user when he register on my site.
This default field is False, and when the user does a certain action (here, buy a product), he has acces on the full web site.

The problem is, I can't add this field when i submit the form.

Here is my code:
all my code are in the app **user**
**user/forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Pseudo", required=True, max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="Prénom", required=True, max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Nom", max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", max_length=150, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))

    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Mot de passe", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))

    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Confirmation mot de passe", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
    }))

    full_access = forms.BooleanField(label="Accès total", required=True, disabled=True, initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

**user/views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        print(form)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            print("here")
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse("accueil"))
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "signup.html", context)
```

So everythings is working, except that the 'full_access' field is not saved in the db and i can't see it on my admin interface
I looked on the internet and i can't figured out why it doesn't word

This full_access field allow the user to go on a page, that others user (who didnt pay) can't have acces.
So I think i can pass by permission, but i would need to create a model for that and I don't need one for this page (or maybe I'm wrong)

I don't even know if my 'full_access' field is saved, because if I write

```
{{ user.full_access }} # Doesn't display anything
{{ user.last_name }} # Display the last name
```

I tried many solutions such as create a model for the form etc... but I don't understand it and it doesn't work

Thank you :)

Comment: `full_access` is not a field in the model, hence it can not be saved to the database.

Comment: Yeah that’s what i figured out but how can i add it to the model?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do so, so I have to post an 'answer':

One option is to extend the base User model. As explained in the Django documentation, you do this with a OneToOneField:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserPlus(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_access = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This approach lets you store information about users, specific to individual users, but technically stored in a new database table (in this example, UserPlus).

But honestly the better approach is probably to define a custom user model. Unfortunately, this likely means dropping your database and rebuilding it after defining your custom user model (in your current db, you are using the default User model provided by django).

The code for writing a Custom User Model is extensive and somewhat beyond the scope of your literal question; so, here's a link to a good tutorial: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model

Comment: Okay that's what I saw on the documentation and on different web site and now I understand
Thank you man